# bash: `set +m` option does not work when placed in the .bashrc file

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, bashrc

If I enter the command:

```
set +m
```

at the end of the .bashrc file, when I run the command:

```
echo $-
```

the option `m` is missing as it should be, but...

If I enter the command:

```
{ sync & } 2> /dev/null
```

and then I press enter again without entering any commands, although I removed the `m` option, the output still appears:

```
[1]+  Done                    sync
```

and only when I rerun the command from the terminal:

```
set +m
```

then the output is no longer shown. In other words, this command has effect only if executed from the terminal.

The question is:

How do I make it work when placed in .bashrc file?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!.. It will work if you put it in as `export PROMPT_COMMAND='set +m'`. You could use `set -o monitor` also.

This probably needs a bug report. I found one for Cygwin: https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/PdJFe7Q6/bash-monitor-mode-remains-enabled-if-disabled-in-bashrc